# How to access mem_ptr after png_set_mem_fn

Tags: c++, libpng

I have the following callbacks:

```
struct my_struct{
    void*(my_alloc)(size_t);
    void (my_free)(void*);
};

void *alloc_fn(png_structp png, png_size_t size){
    my_struct *ptr = static_cast<my_struct*>(/* what here? */);
    return ptr->my_alloc(size);
}

void free_fn(png_structp png, void *mem){
    my_struct *ptr = static_cast<my_struct*>(/* again, madness! */);
    ptr->my_free(mem);
}
```

that I will use like so:

```
int main(){
    png_structp png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    my_struct mem_fn{std::malloc, std::free};

    png_set_mem_fn(png_ptr, &mem_fun, alloc_fn, free_fn);

    // use png_ptr to load png
}
```

[`png_set_mem_fn`](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libpng-png-set-mem-fn-1.html) has the following prototype:

```
void png_set_mem_fn(png_structp png_ptr, png_voidp mem_ptr, png_malloc_ptr malloc_fn, png_free_ptr free_fn);
```

But I have no idea how to retrieve `mem_ptr` inside of `alloc_fn` or `free_fn`.

I have read about [`png_get_progressive_ptr`](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libpng12.png.get.progressive.ptr.1.html) and [`png_get_user_chunk_ptr`](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libpng-png-get-user-chunk-ptr-1.html) which were the only functions I saw in any documentation that looked appropriate. But `png_get_progressive_ptr` returns callbacks and `png_get_user_chunk_ptr` relates to the user data in the *file*.

What exactly am I missing here? how am I supposed to retrieve `mem_fun`?

Comment: "why would you ever need functions pointers in C++?" that's one hell of a bold statement.  `my_struct` is just for the example in this question, my *actual* code is semantically equivalent though.

Comment: `png_get_mem_ptr` looks relevant.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, I mean `mem_ptr` as in the function prototype for `png_set_mem_fn`.

Comment: @AlanStokes This should be an answer, I don't know how I missed it in the documentation!

Comment: See http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt.

Comment: @AlanStokes That is the documentation that I mean I missed it in

Comment: :-) To be fair it is pretty hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `png_get_mem_ptr`. This is documented in http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt.